# Is GNU Radio a good choice still?

Tags: signal-analysis, radio, gnuradio

I'm a newbie at DSP. I am starting a hobbyist project where I plan to monitor 100's of wildlife radio collar frequencies (at my job) and record how many "beeps" per minute are received. My software budget is zero. I have been starting to learn GNU radio and I find most of the tutorials are from 2012 and the many of the blocks are no longer here or soon to be deprecated (WX GUI). Also notice it is not a common tag on Stackexchange. Is GNU Radio a good choice for me?

Comment: GNURadio is in active development and has an active community. It's a very good choice if it supports your hardware. The downsides are (a) very little documentation and (b) it's hard to get started writing your own blocks.

Comment: @MBaz Would you suggest the best forums for basic "why didn't this work" type of questions? Would it be here?

Comment: For gnuradio-specific questions I'd go to the gnuradio mailing lists. They're pretty high traffic. If you need more in-depth help with the theory I'd ask here.

Comment: @MBaz Very little documentation … I could kind of agree on "hard to access documentation", but with the Guided Tutorials for beginners and the really well-citation-backed source code algorithms, I don't think it's the worst documented SDR choice :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's true that some of the tutorials have improved a lot recently.

Comment: @MBaz I hope to improve documentation in the future; target is to make GNU Radio, as whole, both usable and well-documented for SDR beginners and DSP experts alike. Still a long way to go-.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's great news, I wish I had time to contribute more. I've had several students develop tutorials for specific aspects of it, which I plan to release once they're in good enough shape.

Comment: @MBaz something like that is always really really welcome, you know! Even if they're just in somewhat unfinished state, announce them on the mailing list; often, public interest kicks a student's motivation (noone can tell better than me).